# How to force value restriction in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wish to implement a `stack` with `value restriction`.

What I want is that the `pop` and `push` are always talking about exactly the same type all the time.

---

Here is my `sig`.

```
module type MyStackSig = 
sig

  type 'a stack

  exception EmptyStack

  val create : unit -> 'a stack
  val push : 'a stack -> 'a -> unit
  val pop : 'a stack -> 'a
  val is_empty : 'a stack -> bool
  val size : 'a stack -> int

end;;
```

---

Is this sig enough for the `value restriction`?

**I mean will `push` and `pop` be talking about the same type all the time?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signature looks correct. The types tell that push and pop handle the same content type when they take the same stack. The type parameter 'a of stack ensures it.

```
let st = create () in
push st 1;
print_string (pop st)
```

is ill typed, since the st cannot have a polymorphic type due to value restriction, however, it is used for more than one type: int stack and string stack: "they do not talk about the same type" for one stack st, whose parameter type is value-restricted.

On the other hand, the following is well-typed:

```
let st1 = create () in
let st2 = create () in
push st1 1;
print_string (pop st2) (* it should raise EmptyStack, but do not care it here *)
```

Here, push and pop talk about different types, but of different stacks. So, no problem.

(Relaxed) value restriction is not something you can force. You are forced to live with it. It is a limitation of the type system for typing of side effects in OCaml.

Comment: you should really put emphasis on the last line, otherwise excellent answer!

Comment: What's the scope of `'a`? I mean the `'a` inside `val create : unit -> 'a stack` is the same as the one inside `val push : 'a stack -> 'a -> unit`?

Comment: The scope is local. This, however, is sufficient to force values pushed and pulled from a given stack to have all the same type. The reason is that the stack is created of type `'_a stack` where `_a` is some unknown type; but once you push a value of known type, or pull a value and use it in a context imposing its type, then `_a` gets assigned a definite value. Note the difference between `'a` ("any type `'a`", with implicit universal quantification at the beginning of the declaration) and `'_a` ("some fixed type `_a` that we do not know yet").